# how to join 2 tables into 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

how to join 2 tables into 1 in mysql ?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `p`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `p`;
CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of p
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('1', 'jimmy');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('2', 'tina');
```

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `t`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `value` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('1', 'name', '111');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('1', 'age', '30');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('2', 'bag', 'miki');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('2', 'boy friend', 'jimmy');
```

the picture show what I want to get.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.id, p.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(tag, ':', value)) tags
FROM    p
        INNER JOIN t
            ON p.iD = t.id
GROUP   BY p.id, p.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edbb5/3)
- [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║           TAGS            ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ jimmy ║ age:30,name:111           ║
║  2 ║ tina  ║ bag:miki,boy friend:jimmy ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```